# MySQL - Any addtional indexes would speed up this query?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I see that my query does full table scan and takes a lot of time. I heard that making indexes would speed this up and I have added some to the tables. Is there any other indexes I should create to make this query faster?

My query is:

```
SELECT p.id, n.people_type_id, n.full_name, n.post, p.nick, 
p.key_name, p.email, p.internal_user_id FROM email_routing e 
JOIN people_emails p ON p.id=e.receiver_email_id 
JOIN people n ON n.id = p.people_id
WHERE e.message_id = 897360 AND e.basket=1
```

Here is the EXPLAIN result:

> ```
> EXPLAIN SELECT p.id, n.people_type_id, n.full_name, n.post, p.nick, 
> p.key_name, p.email, p.internal_user_id FROM email_routing e 
> JOIN people_emails p ON p.id=e.receiver_email_id 
> JOIN people n ON n.id = p.people_id 
> WHERE e.message_id = 897360 AND e.basket=1
> ```

```
id select_type table partitions type possible_keys key  key_len ref         rows      filtered   Extra
1  SIMPLE      n     NULL       ALL  PRIMARY       NULL NULL    NULL        1         100.00     NULL
1  SIMPLE      p     NULL       ALL  PRIMARY       NULL NULL    NULL        3178      10.00      Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
1  SIMPLE      e     NULL       ref  bk1           bk1  4       server.p.id 440       1.00       Using where; Using
```

And here are the tables strucutre:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE people_emails; 
CREATE TABLE `people_emails` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `nick` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `key_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `people_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `activity` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `internal_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=22114 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

SHOW CREATE TABLE email_routing; 
CREATE TABLE `email_routing` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `message_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `sender_email_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `receiver_email_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `basket` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `popup` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `tm` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 KEY `id` (`id`),
 KEY `bk1` (`receiver_email_id`,`status`,`sender_email_id`,`message_id`,`basket`),
 KEY `bk2` (`sender_email_id`,`tm`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1054618 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


SHOW CREATE TABLE people; 
CREATE TABLE `people` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `fname` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET cp1251 NOT NULL,
 `lname` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET cp1251 NOT NULL,
 `patronymic` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET cp1251 NOT NULL,
 `gender` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `full_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT ' ',
 `category` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `people_type_id` int(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `tags` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET cp1251 NOT NULL,
 `job` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET cp1251 NOT NULL,
 `post` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET cp1251 NOT NULL,
 `profession` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET cp1251 DEFAULT NULL,
 `zip` varchar(16) CHARACTER SET cp1251 NOT NULL,
 `country` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `region` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `city` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET cp1251 NOT NULL,
 `address` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET cp1251 NOT NULL,
 `address_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `inner` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
 `contact_through` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
 `next_call` date NOT NULL,
 `additional` text CHARACTER SET cp1251 NOT NULL,
 `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `changed` datetime NOT NULL,
 `status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `nick` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `birthday` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `last_update_ts` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `area` text NOT NULL,
 `reviewed_` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
 `phones_old` text NOT NULL,
 `post_sticker` text NOT NULL,
 `permissions` int(120) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `internal_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `most_used` (`category`,`status`,`city`,`lname`,`next_call`),
 KEY `registrars` (`category`,`status`,`contact_through`,`next_call`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `lname` (`lname`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `fname` (`fname`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `mname` (`patronymic`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `Full Name` (`full_name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=415009 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

How to choose columns for building indexes, should I pick text columnts too or that only will work with numer columnts

Comment: In general, you should index all fields that participate in a join.

Comment: @RobertHarvey even for text fields like email subjects and bodies?

Comment: Are they participating in a join?

Comment: oh, you are right, they are not, so what's the rule - all columnts from join and where clause?

Comment: Start with the joins and the largest tables first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`email_routing` needs

```
INDEX ( message_id, basket,  -- first, in either order
        receiver_email_id )  -- for "covering"
```

Your `bk1` *starts* with `receiver_email_id`; this is *not* nearly as good.

1. Include column(s) in `WHERE` that are tested with `=`.
2. Include other columns from `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, and `ORDER BY` (none in your case); the order is important, but beyond the scope of *this* discussion.
3. Include any other columns of the same table used anywhere in the query -- this is to make it a "covering" index.  But don't bother if this would lead to more than, say, 5 columns or would involve `TEXT`, which cannot be in an index.

Then move on to the other tables.  In both `JOINs`, it seems that they would be hit by their `PRIMARY KEYs`  (`JOIN x ON x.id = ...`)

More discussion: [*Cookbook for creating indexes*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

On other issues...

You really should move to InnoDB.  As of 5.6, it includes `FULLTEXT`, but there are some [*differences*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb).  In particular, you may need more fulltext indexes.  For example, `MATCH(lname, fname)` requires `FULLTEXT(lname, fname)`.

Do you really want to stick to `cp1251`?  It limits your internalization mostly to English, Russian, Bulgarian, Serbian and Macedonian.  And it is unclear how well `FULLTEXT` (MyISAM or InnoDB) will work with those non-English languages.

`INTs` are always 4 bytes; consider using smaller versions.

Is there really only one `people`?  The Optimizer decided that was the best table to start with, but it wasn't.  I'm hoping my improved index on `email_routing` will trick it into starting with that table -- which will definitely be optimal.

Answer (score 1):

The table *email_routing* seem to have 1054618 rows .

And you try to find one row , by message_id .

```
e.message_id = 897360
```

*BUT* message_id must be indexed to speed-up the query .

*message_id* is part of the index `bk1` , but this is not enough because *message_id* is not the first columns of the index .